# Implementing Interfaces Explictly in F#

Tags: .net, interface, f#, explicit-interface, explicit-implementation

Ok, C# has [Explictit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
I'l like to do similar in F#.

I have some Interfaces (and classes)

```
type IState = interface
    abstract member Update : IAction-> IState
    ...
end
type IEnviroment = interface
    abstract member Update : IAction-> IEnviroment
    ...
    end


type IBoard  = 
    inherit IState
    inherit IEnviroment
    abstract member Update : Move -> IBoard
    ...

[<AbstractClass>]
and Move ()= 
    abstract member Apply : IBoard -> IBoard
    interface IAction with        
        override this.Cost = 1M
```

So the problem I have is that Update is defined 3 times differently.
So I need the equivelent of C#'s [Explictit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
I'me thinking I'ld implement it in the interface (since that is legit in F#) - it would just consist of some typecasts.

My understanding is that all interface implementation in F# is explcit, in classes,
But once an interface inherits from another inferface, then you only (explicitly) implement that one.
(so my Board class only implments I Board)

Comment: Can't you rename the methods? I think it's confusing to have three methods with the same name that do different things in one interface. And it would solve your problem too.

Comment: Actually they all do the same thing (on the same objects even).
Its just the other stuff the interfaces provide/require is different.
They do the same thing for different purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the syntax `member this.IState.Update` in the implementation of `IBoard`, but the compiler rejected it.

I don't see a way in the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997189) to do what you want.

Here is a work-around in for such name clashes, using an abstract class to forward calls to each interface.

```
type I1 =
    interface
        abstract F : unit -> unit
    end

type I2 =
    interface
        abstract F : unit -> unit
    end

type II =
    interface
        inherit I1
        inherit I2
        abstract F : unit -> unit
    end

[<AbstractClass>]
type III() =
    abstract F1 : unit -> unit
    abstract F2 : unit -> unit
    abstract F3 : unit -> unit
    interface I1 with
        member this.F() = this.F1()
    interface I2 with
        member this.F() = this.F2()

type Works() =
    inherit III()
    override this.F1() = printfn "F1"
    override this.F2() = printfn "F2"
    override this.F3() = printfn "F3"

type Fails() =
    interface II with
        member this.F() = ()
```